# Simulating slow connections with Apache TCPMon

Tags: java, performance, connection, simulation, tcpmon

I need to simulate a slow client in order to test some processing inside my Java server. My idea was to stub a small Java client and get some tool for simulating a slow connection. In my view, that should be enough.

Googling here and there I found Apache TCPMon, which appears capable of simulating my slowdowns, and decided to put it at work.

The way I understand it -- documentation is very limited -- I'd need to create a nre TCPMon that acts as a Proxy, check the 'Simulate Slow Connection' and configure it. Nice and easy.

I've thus created a TCPMon on port 8081, and turned 'HTTP proxy support' on for localhost:8080. I'm then running my Java server on localhost:8080, and to my understanding I should be able to see the (delayed) message pointing my browser to `http://localhost:8081`. Instead, all I can see when I do that is the following exception:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: lib/img/body-bg.png
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:583)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:480)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:429)
    at org.apache.ws.commons.tcpmon.Connection.run(Connection.java:276)
```

I'll appreciate the help of anyone shedding some light upon this, and also suggesting how I can use TCPMon to the extent I described above in a scenario where both client and server run on my laptop.

Thanks.